# What does a curl_error_56 and a HTTP_error_502 have in common?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, slack-commands

I am working on a Chatbot in Slack that sends a POST request to `http://localhost:44331/values/api` an `.NET Core API` that i built in `C#`. In the Post request is a `response_url` in the body I can use to send back the needed information.

So I have been trying to make this work for about two weeks now and used a fiddler and to mimic the request so I can make some changes on the body and the headers to see if that makes a difference.

So after a lot of errors I have come to two specific errors that haven't changed for a long while.

### sent with the Slack Chatbot: `curl_error_56`

There really isnt much I can change in this matter except the `url` I want to send the request to.
In fact this request has never even reached the post method in my `API`.

- [image]

Thats what the Slackbot answers
[image]

### sent with fiddler: `HTTP error 400`

I used [Requestbin](https://requestbin.com/) to get the information that has been sent by the bot and copied it into the composer in fiddler.
[image]

I am a total novice to Web programming in any kind of way so I really don't know what they have in common.
Are those errors coming because I am using localhost?
What am I missing?

here is the request so you can copy it if needed

```
host: localhost:44331
Accept: application/json,*/*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)
X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1569238196
X-Slack-Signature: v0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 381
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Not having the useful stuff as images would be a good start.

Comment: @tripleee Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got some help by a friend and he explained to me that Slack is unable to access my localhost, because it is not a local app. It is taking its information from the web and making it send a request to my localhost is useless because it is not a static IP.
What i need is an Endpoint.
I can get one by requesting it from my ISP (Internet Service Provider) or getting myself a server which already has an static IP.

Thanks for any help you wanted to provide.